# In Google Optimize, measure visits to another page in the same session

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

I'm fairly new to Optimize, so  apologies if this is a basic question I just haven't figured out.

I wish to perform an A/B test measuring users' engagement with a sign-up form accessed via a particular page `/ingress-page` in two situations:

1. `/ingress-page` contains a link to `/form-page` which contains the sign-up form
2. `/ingress-page` itself embeds the form

In both cases, the form is provided by a third party, so is embedded into the page via an `iframe` - I therefore cannot hook an event onto the form submitting. However, when the form is submitted, the user will be redirected to `/thank-you-page`.

I would therefore like to set my Optimize test to run on `/ingress-page`, with the baseline having a link to `/form-page` and Variant 1 embedding the form directly, with an objective of "User visits `/thank-you-page` in the same session".

I don't seem to be able to make this work. I have tried using a custom objective "Page views: page equals `/thank-you-page`", and I have also tried using an Analytics goal "Destination: `/thank-you-page`", but in both cases I am seeing 0 conversions (I know there have been some conversions, because I tested the form myself).

Is it possible to give Optimize a goal of this form?

Comment: Are you seeing the conversions in GA, just not in Optimize? I'm assuming so since this question is about Optimize, but please correct me if that is not the case. How long have you left it before checking? There is no version of Real-Time for Optimize - you won't be able to see data until the following day.

Comment: I see events-matching-the-goal in Analytics, but none in Analytics' view of the Optimize experiment, if you understand me. I let it run until it counted the sessions I tested myself, but had 0 conversions.

Comment: Optimize appears to have changed a bit since the last time I used it, but it should certainly be possible to use this sort of thing as your goal. When you say "events matching the goal" I assume you mean pageviews, rather than GA Events? If there's any way you can add screenshots of what you're looking at in Optimize and GA that would probably help. Right now I would suggest trying a Pageview custom objective in Optimize with the match set to "regex" or "starts with" instead of "equals" to rule out problems due to inexact URL match.